# proxy all network communication in bash session

Tags: networking, bash, ssh, terminal, proxy

Is it possible to specify a proxy for all network communication in a bash session?  I suspect it is possible to do it using ssh but I'd rather not use it if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux there is `proxychains` and `proxychains-ng`. I believe the latter is called `proxychains4` in Ubuntu. The usage it like this:

```
proxychains4 some_program     # see the manual to learn about config files
```

or

```
proxychains4 -f configfile.conf some_program
```

---

> Is it possible to specify a proxy for all network communication in a bash session?

Basically yes.

```
proxychains4 bash
```

The tool works by using [`LD_PRELOAD` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426260/10765659) to preload its shared object which does the real job. First of all the `bash` itself is proxified (usually you don't expect your shell to initiate network connections, but Bash does this for special redirections like `foo > /dev/tcp/host/port`, they will be proxified). The variable is in the environment so any command invoked in this Bash session will be affected.

```
# from within our proxified Bash
wget -O /dev/null superuser.com     # also proxified
```

However

- if our proxified Bash (or any proxified command) spawns a child whose `LD_PRELOAD` doesn't point to the right object, the child won't be proxified, e.g.:

  ```
  # from within our proxified Bash
  LD_PRELOAD="" wget -O /dev/null superuser.com     # not proxified
  ```
- if our proxified Bash (or any proxified command) execs to a new process (possibly a new instance of itself) with `LD_PRELOAD` not pointing to the right object, the resulting process won't be proxified, e.g.:

  ```
  # from within our proxified Bash
  unset LD_PRELOAD
  exec bash
  # now we are in non-proxified Bash, it replaced the proxified one
  wget -O /dev/null superuser.com     # not proxified
  ```

Comment: thanks for this.  i `brew install`ed this on mac.  it doesn't seem to be working.  after filling out the config file's `[ProxyList]` entry to `socks5 127.0.0.1 8888`, `curl -x 127.0.0.1:8888 ipecho.net/plain` and `proxychains4 curl ipecho.net/plain` give different results.  thoughts?

Comment: @WalrustheCat How about `curl -x socks5://127.0.0.1:8888 ipecho.net/plain`?

Comment: that one works  

Comment: ok figured out what this was!  MacOS SIP protects the binaries.  You have to copy them to another location (`cp $(which curl) ~/...`) and then `proxychains4` that binary and it will work.  cheers to this guy: https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/issues/78#issuecomment-138435817

Answer (score 0):

You can set a proxy that is used by most programs supporting SOCKS (i.e. `telnet`, `wget` and the like) by exporting it as an environment variable:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/ 
export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyhost:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/
```