# proxy is working only for browser, but not in cli

Tags: linux, proxy, fedora

I am using fedora-30.
my network is behind a proxy. After setting up the proxy, when I opened the browser, username/password prompt came and I can access the internet through the browser.

But, from a terminal, ssh/ping etc not working, neither mail client like evolution.

Fedora  set up system-wide proxy through settings -> network, so that all my applications should be able to acces the proxy. But unfortunately it is not working.

Kindly help

Comment: Related: [*proxy all network communication in bash session*](https://superuser.com/q/1392538/432690).

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! You may get more answers to your question if you ask a specific question. I have edited your question to include specifically asking about if you can add system-wide proxy settings so all your apps can use it, including CLI ones. Hope this helps!

Comment: By "proxy" you mean HTTP-proxy? That won't proxy your SSH nor ping. On CLI, can you check with cur/links/lynx if HTTP works with any of those.

Comment: i mean http, https and socks