# How to monitor a process' network traffic?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm using [Parrot OS](https://parrotlinux.org/) which is Debian-based. I'm doing [this CTF](https://capturetheflag.withgoogle.com/#beginners/) and am playing around on a networking part.

I have a binary called `init_sat` which seems to connect to a server to check some stuff. (I won't go deep into my findings to avoid spoilers.) I'd like a way to monitor the traffic of the program.

I've tried using:

```
# PID of init_sat is 16247
$ strace -p 16247 -e trace=network -s 10000
strace: Process 16247 attached
```

but nothing seems to get logged as I do some stuff with `init_sat`.

I've also tried:

```
# PID of init_sat is 16281
$ sudo netstat -taucp | grep 16281
```

but also got no output.

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), as I've read, can't conveniently monitor a single process. I couldn't find a good way to redirect the traffic to [zaproxy](https://www.zaproxy.org/) or [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) either.

What a good way I can monitor all traffic used be a single process? It can be monitoring requests like Burp or packets like with wireshark

Comment: Possible approach: [`proxychains`](https://superuser.com/a/1392848/432690). Setting up the proxy according to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1200601/432690) may be needed.